# is there an R function for Stata's xtnbreg?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, stata

Have been using Stata to run negative binomial regressions in a replication.  Not sure what is under the hood on how Stata does this, but wanted to know if there is an R function/package that does the same thing?  The R will give me a better idea of how this works, since I can see the code.

Answer (score 4):

Look into the `glm.nb` function in the `MASS` package.  If you're interested in what's happening "under the hood," you can see the source code of the function by just entering its name at the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

If you're more comfortable using R, then that's probably the way to go; however, if you're interested in what's "under the hood" in Stata, you can always see what's going on in much the same way as in R by using

```
set trace on
```

to see what code is running (or download `tr` from SSC) or using

```
viewsource xtnbreg.ado
```

to see the actual code that is run by `xtnbreg`.

If you're interested in how Stata is calculating the results in `xtnbreg` there is a detailed discussion of the likelihood function in the [XT] manual page 367-370 with references included.