# Why does xtnbreg, fe in Stata produce different findings than femlm and glm.nb (both with fixed effects) in R?

Tags: r, stata

I have estimated the following negative binomial regression model with group fixed effects in Stata. The data are time series cross sectional. The *panelvar* is group and the *timevar* is time.

```
tsset group time
xtnbreg y x1 x2 x3 + x4 + x5, fe
```

I want to replicate these findings in R. To do this, I have tried these 4 models:

```
nb1 <- femlm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 | group, panel.id = ~group + time, family = "negbin", mydata)
nb2 <- fenegbin(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 | group, panel.id = ~group + time, mydata)
nb3 <- glm.nb(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + factor(group), data=mydata)
nb4 <- glmmadmb(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + factor(group), data = mydata, family="nbinom")
```

The results produced by nb1-4 are all identical, but *different* from the results produced by xtnbreg in Stata. The coefficients, standard errors, and p-values are all substantively different.

I have tried replicating a standard negative binomial regression in Stata and R and have been able to do so successfully.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? I have reviewed related posts on this forum (such as this one: [is there an R function for Stata's xtnbreg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508747/is-there-an-r-function-for-statas-xtnbreg)) and have not found any answers.

Comment: Is there any chance we can have a [mcve]?  Looking at https://www.stata-press.com/manuals/errata/stata6/i/xtnbreg.pdf, it says "a  conditional likelihood  is  used  in  which  the  dispersion  parameter drops out of the estimation". See also https://statisticalhorizons.com/fe-nbreg .... `?fixest::femlm` also strongly suggests that it is is using *unconditional* ML ...

Comment: If you want to know "what is the difference between conditional and unconditional ML in this context and why does it matter?" that might be a question for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: More questions: what does `xtnbreg` do with / assume about the time variable?

Comment: Thank you! I had not noticed this difference between the two commands. I will look into this further and will follow up if it ends up being the source of the issue.

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, you should post your answer as an *answer*, rather than as an edit to your question (self-answering is encouraged on Stack Overflow - there may be a waiting period before you can self-answer as a new user, but I suspect it's elapsed already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED** (mostly): The R code that reproduces the results generated by xtnbreg, fe in Stata:

```
nb5 <- pglm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 ,family = negbin, data = mydata, effect = "individual", model="within", index = "group")
```

I found the solution on RPubs: https://rpubs.com/cuborican/xtpoisson.
I still do not know *why* this works, only that it does. I suspect that Ben is correct and it has something to do with estimating conditional vs unconditional ML. If anyone knows for sure, please share.